# PrimeFaces tabmenu not changing index

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using `p:tabMenu` component. I have 4 menuitems, each one redirects to a different jsf page but the problem is that the page is returned without changing the `activeindex` and `activeindex` remains same with the initial value which is 0.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<p:tabMenu activeIndex="0">
    <p:menuitem value="Home" url="Menu.jsf" icon="ui-icon-star"/>  
    <p:menuitem value="Fabricants" url="/pagess/pagesFabricant/Fabricant.jsf" icon="ui-icon-wrench" />  
    <p:menuitem value="Composants" url="/pagess/pagesComposant/Composant.jsf" icon="ui-icon-search"/>  
    <p:menuitem value="Dossier d'equivalence" url="DEQ.jsf" icon="ui-icon-document"/>  
</p:tabMenu> 

</ui:composition>
```

How can I solve this problem knowing that should change automatically ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use EL to set it at the managed bean level. So like this

```
<p:tabMenu activeIndex="#{myBean.myActiveIndex}">
    <p:menuitem value="Home" url="Menu.jsf" icon="ui-icon-star" action="#{myBean.setActiveIndex(0)}"/>  
    <p:menuitem value="Fabricants" url="/pagess/pagesFabricant/Fabricant.jsf" action="#{myBean.setActiveIndex(1)}" icon="ui-icon-wrench" />  
</p:tabMenu>
```

Comment: Thx for your cooperation :)

Comment: You might need a `<h:form>` around your tab menu so that it can send the value to your bean

Comment: Is it really working? When you have both url and action attributes specified, url is taking precedence and issuing a GET request without invoking action method. So the activeIndex value won't be set with value u r passing thru myBean.setActiveIndex().

Comment: @sivaprasadreddy.k: I currently dont have primefaces with me to test, but if that happen to you, you can use POST to navigate as well. So dont specify url, but your action method return the string of navigation path. So your method look something like this `public String navigateAndSetActiveIndex(String url, int index)`. Just make sure that you append `faces-redirect=true` on your url to do POST-REDIRECT - GET

Answer (score 1):

i resolved the activeIndex problem with a javascript workaround. I created a inputHidden and i changed its value when i have a onclick event.

I have a tabBean managed bean that creates my menu and storages activeIndex:

```
@SessionScope
@ManagedBean(name="tabBean") 
public class TabBean{

private int activeIndex;

 public IMenu getMenu(){
  IMenuModel simpleMenuModel = new DefaultMenuModel();

  MenuItem mi = new MenuItem();
  mi.setValue("Home");
  mi.setIcon("ui-icon-home");
  mi.setActionExpression(UITools.ExternalContext.getMethodValue("home", new Class[]{}));
  mi.setAjax(false);
  simpleMenuModel.addMenuItem(mi);
  ...
  return menu;
 }
}
```

and in my xhtml page I have:

```
<script>
  function setCurrentIndex(index){
    var activeIndexName = PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('tabForm:activeIndex_hidden');
    var component = $(activeIndexName);
    component.val(index);
  }
</script>
<p:outputPanel id="menuPanel" layout="block"> 
   <h:form id="tabForm"> 
     <p:tabMenu  id="tabMenu" model="#{tabBean.menu}" activeIndex="#{tabBean.activeIndex}" />  
     <h:inputHidden id="activeIndex_hidden" value="{tabBean.activeIndex}"/> 
   </h:form>    
</p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Thx for your helep I did the same but like this

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:tabMenu activeIndex="#{loginBean.activeindex}">  
    <p:menuitem value="Accueil"  icon="ui-icon-star" action="#{loginBean.Dirige(0)}" />
    <p:menuitem value="Fabricants"  icon="ui-icon-wrench"  action="#{loginBean.Dirige(1)}" /> 
    <p:menuitem value="Composants" icon="ui-icon-search"  action="#{loginBean.Dirige(2)}"/> 
    <p:menuitem value="Dossier d'equivalence"  icon="ui-icon-document"  action="#{loginBean.Dirige(3)}"/> 
</p:tabMenu>
```

and set activeindex with the parametere in Dirige :)